# R: how to simplify output of rerun (from purrr)?

Tags: r, purrr

(This is my first question on Stackflow: I hope I am posing it correclty)

I am using rerun (from tidyverse purrr) to repeat some calculations. Here is a very simplified example (it may seem nonsensical but it illustrates  the point)

```
library(tidyverse)

# Function to do the calculation 
do_rerun <- function(data_in){
  data_out <- data_in %>%   
    group_by(id) %>%
    transmute(result = do_calculation(x1, x2)) %>% 
    ungroup()
  return(data_out)
}

# Some test data
(test_data <- tibble(id = c("1","2","3","1","2","3","1","2","3"), 
                    day = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                    x1 = runif(9), 
                    x2 = runif(9)) %>% 
  arrange(id,day))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  id      day     x1     x2
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 1         1 0.195  0.0854
2 1         2 0.884  0.0863
3 1         3 0.539  0.240 
4 2         1 0.696  0.262 
5 2         2 0.752  0.663 
6 2         3 0.477  0.252 
7 3         1 0.0387 0.494 
8 3         2 0.286  0.589 
9 3         3 0.0249 0.870 

# Do the calculation .n = 3 times
# The output of reun is a list,
# which in this case is a list of 3 unnamed tibbles
# each of which has an id and result column
(test <- rerun(.n = 3, do_rerun(test_data)))

# Output

[[1]]
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  id    result
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 1     0.0167
2 1     0.0763
3 1     0.129 
4 2     0.182 
5 2     0.499 
6 2     0.121 
7 3     0.0191
8 3     0.168 
9 3     0.0217

[[2]]
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  id    result
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 1     0.0167
2 1     0.0763
3 1     0.129 
4 2     0.182 
5 2     0.499 
6 2     0.121 
7 3     0.0191
8 3     0.168 
9 3     0.0217

[[3]]
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  id    result
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 1     0.0167
2 1     0.0763
3 1     0.129 
4 2     0.182 
5 2     0.499 
6 2     0.121 
7 3     0.0191
8 3     0.168 
9 3     0.0217
```

I would like to convert this list of three tibbles into a single tibble that contains id (from the first tibble) followed by result1, result2, result3 (i.e. the result field from each of the three tibbles). I can access individual columns with

```
id_tibble <- as_tibble(test[[1]][["id"]])
```

and

```
result_tibble <- as_tibble(test[[1]][["result"]])
```

What I would like to do (for the result columns at least) is this:

```
new_tibble <- as_tibble(test[[1:3]][["result"]])
```

But it throws an error ("Error in test[[1:3]][["result"]] : subscript out of bounds").

The final structure that I would like to obtain is:

```
id    result1 result2 result3
<chr> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     0.0167  0.0167  0.0167
1     0.0763  0.0763  0.0763
1     0.129   0.129   0.129 
2     0.182   etc.
```

Perhaps the way to do this is with the map command in purrr (or one of its variants) but I'm darned if I can figure it out!

Comment: `bind_cols(test)` is what you need

Comment: Thank you: so simple! That produces output of the form id, result, id1, result1, id2, result2. Is there a way to simultaneously include only id (i.e. not including id1, id2)?

Comment: in that case `bind_cols(test) %>%  select(-matches("id.+"))`

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick solution: create a large dataframe and drop the duplicate `id` columns:

```
test %>%
    purrr::map_dfc(cbind) %>%
    dplyr::select(-matches("id.+"))
```

(edit: added alternative below to stay within dplyr; i.e., this will result in a `tibble`)

```
test %>%
    dplyr::bind_cols() %>%
    dplyr::select(-matches("id.+"))
```

I am assuming that you know that in your example all three results are the same 
 and that in the actual problem the results are different. I am also assuming 
 that you want to rerun the analysis by more than 3 times. (if I am mistaken, please let me know)

Comment: Thank you, this works! Yes I am aware that in this simple example the results are the same (the actual calculation is more complex, with different results for each rerun). In the real example rerun will be many time greater than 3. The ultimate aim is to (for example) find the smallest and largest value across all result columns, by row.